# SQLite data dictionary tables and columns

Tags: sqlite, data-dictionary

Can you tell us the names of all tables and table columns in the SQLite data dictionary?

Update:

I was using this information for a Basic4Android app I'm developing.

Here is the actual segment of coding I used:

```
' Create the PeopleToVisit table which holds lookup data about each visit.
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------
If SQL.ExecQuerySingleResult( _
    "SELECT count(name) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='PeopleToVisit'") _
    = 0 Then

    ToastMessageShow("Creating the People to Visit table.", False)

    ' Create it now since it doesn't yet exist.
    '------------------------------------------
    SQL.ExecNonQuery("CREATE TABLE PeopleToVisit (" & _
        "Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " & _
        "FirstName TEXT, " & _
        "LastName TEXT, " & _
        "Address1 TEXT, " & _
        "Address2 TEXT, " & _
        "City TEXT, " & _
        "State TEXT, " & _
        "Zip TEXT " & _
        ")")
End If

' New table columns for Version 1.2
'----------------------------------

' Coding for when new data columns need to be added to the database table.
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------
strCreateTableStatement = _
    SQL.ExecQuerySingleResult("SELECT sql " & _
                                "FROM sqlite_master " & _
                               "WHERE Type = 'table' AND name = 'PeopleToVisit'")

' Check if the new columns are in the table.
'-------------------------------------------
If strCreateTableStatement.IndexOf("PrimaryPhone TEXT") = -1 Then

    ' We need to add the new columns to the table.
    '---------------------------------------------
    SQL.ExecNonQuery("ALTER TABLE PeopleToVisit ADD COLUMN PrimaryPhone TEXT")
    SQL.ExecNonQuery("ALTER TABLE PeopleToVisit ADD COLUMN SecondaryPhone TEXT")
    SQL.ExecNonQuery("ALTER TABLE PeopleToVisit ADD COLUMN Email TEXT")
    SQL.ExecNonQuery("ALTER TABLE PeopleToVisit ADD COLUMN LastVisitNote TEXT")     
End If
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To list all tables in a database

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'
```

To list all columns in a table

```
pragma table_info(table_name)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used sqlite_master to find the information. Please see the update I made to the post.

Comment: You can use the `pragma table_info(table_name)` as you would a `SELECT` statement such as `SQL.ExecQuery("pragma table_info('PeopleToVisit')")`

Comment: Thanks for the SQL statement example. I will try that. :-)